# Using broom::augment Panel data models

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to ask,

There is a issue when using `augment` function in panel data, especially on first-differences estimator.

Is there a way how to get using function `augment` or any approach as well how to retrive regression table even for first-difference estimator? Works perfectly fine for other methods.

```
library(foreign)
library(plm)

crime <- read.dta("http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/crime4.dta")

crime.p <- pdata.frame(crime,index=c("county","year"))

panel1 <- plm(log(crmrte) ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density, data = crime.p, model = "within")
panel2 <- plm(log(crmrte) ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density, data = crime.p, model = "random")
panel3 <- plm(log(crmrte) ~ polpc + prbconv + avgsen + density, data = crime.p, model = "fd")


broom::augment(panel1)
broom::augment(panel2)
broom::augment(panel3)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72294844/4640346

Answer (score 1):

You can access the components of what the broom::augment function produces manually. The code below might give you some guidance. I first access the model as part of panel3 list and then join the residuals by name. In some instances, the residuals are missing which I suspect is the reason why broom::augment seems not to be working.

```
data.frame("rownames" = row.names(panel3$model), panel3$model) %>%
      left_join(data.frame("rownames" = names(panel3$residuals), "resid" = panel3$residuals))
```

Comment: it will be better if you give some explanation or comments to your code.

Comment: I tried to explain what the code does. Hope it is now a bit clearer.