# Regression in first differences with packages `plm` and `broom`

Tags: panel-data, plm, broom

I'm estimating a linear regression in first-differences straight out of the textbook:

- James H. Stock and Mark W. Watson, Introduction to Econometrics, Pearson, 4th Edition.
- Christoph Hanck, Martin Arnold, Alexander Gerber, and Martin Schmelzer, Introduction to Econometrics with R, https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/10-rwpd.html
- Data from package AER, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AER/AER.pdf

I'm estimating the model in first-differences with the `plm()` function from the `plm` package and extracting residuals with the `augment()` function from the `broom` package. I'm getting an error message and suspect I may not be using the `"fd"` option correctly and/or misusing `augment()`. A similar attempt for `model="pooling"` appears to work. Help appreciated!

```
library(AER)
data(Fatalities)
Fatalities$fatality <- Fatalities$fatal / Fatalities$pop * 10000

library(plm)
library(broom)

plm.pool <- plm(fatality ~ beertax, data=Fatalities, model="pooling")
tidy(plm.pool)  # ok
augment(plm.pool)  # ok


plm.fd <- plm(fatality ~ beertax, data=Fatalities, 
              index=c("state", "year"), 
              model="fd")
tidy(plm.fd)  # looks ok
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept) -0.00314    0.0119   -0.263    0.792
2 beertax      0.0137     0.285     0.0480   0.962


augment(plm.fd)  # not ok

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ".resid", value = c(`2` = 0.219840293582125,  : 
  replacement has 288 rows, data has 336
In addition: Warning message:
In get(.Generic)(e1, e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

**EDIT: A WORKAROUND**

So I suspect the problem has something to do with the fact that the model returned by `plm` and the residuals do not have the same number of rows:

`length(row.names(plm.fd$model))` is 336

`length(names(plm.fd$residuals))` is 288.

Can someone tell me if the following is the correct way to get residuals and fitted values from the first-difference estimation?

```
data.frame(".rownames" = row.names(plm.fd$model), plm.fd$model) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(".rownames" = names(resid(plm.fd)), 
                       ".fitted" = fitted(plm.fd),
                       ".resid" = resid(plm.fd)
                       )) -> Fatalities.augmented
head(Fatalities.augmented)

  .rownames fatality  beertax       .fitted       .resid
1         1  2.12836 1.539379            NA           NA
2         2  2.34848 1.788991  0.0034166261  0.219840294
3         3  2.33643 1.714286 -0.0010225479 -0.007890716
4         4  2.19348 1.652542 -0.0008451287 -0.138968054
5         5  2.66914 1.609907 -0.0005835833  0.479380363
6         6  2.71859 1.560000 -0.0006831177  0.053269973
```

References:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/broom.pdf

Reference for Edit:

- [Using broom::augment Panel data models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552625/using-broomaugment-panel-data-models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a misunderstanding or non-special casing the first-difference (FD) panel model in `broom::augment_columns`: the function assumes the residuals of the FD model have the same length as the predicted values.

More concretly, this line: `ret$.resid <- residuals0(x)` (https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/blob/069c21e903174fcf5d491091b7c347a9fdcd2999/R/utilities.R#L256)

FD models compress the data, so the number of residuals is lower than the number of observations used for model estimation. You can see that in the `summary` output:

```
summary(panel3) # FD model
Oneway (individual) effect First-Difference Model

[...]
Balanced Panel: n = 90, T = 7, N = 630
Observations used in estimation: 540
[...]
```

While the model has an input of 630 observations, after FD transformation, only 540 transformed observations are used as one loses one observation per group (individual dimension) -> 630 - 90 = 540.

The `broom:augment_columns` wants to put the predicted values (630) and the residuals (540) in the same data frame, this is bound to fail. If they want to do it, they could pad values with NA (e.g., the first row for each individual set to NA).

My suggestion is to make developers/the maintainer of broom aware of this issue (and maybe this post). plm's FD panel models are identified via `plm_object$args$model == "fd"`.

Comment: tappek beat me to it! https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/1102